# Proving surjectivity and injectivity without a concept of cardinality?

Tags: set-theory

The question stems from a text on set theory in which functions are dealt with much more early than ordinals and cardinals. However, I would like to state the proposition in the section on functions as opposed to cardinals. Yet, in any way (that is reasonably rigorous and elegant) I have tried to prove the statement I find that "the size of the sets" has to be taken into account and I do not know how to handle that without cardinality.

Proposition:

Let $a$ and $b$ be finite sets and $f: a \rightarrow b$ be a function. Then

$$\forall f: \texttt{Endo}(f) \wedge \texttt{Inj}(f) \rightarrow \texttt{Surj}(f)$$
 and 
$$\forall f: \texttt{Endo}(f) \wedge \texttt{Surj}(f) \rightarrow \texttt{Inj}(f)$$
and therefore 
$$\forall f: [\texttt{Endo}(f) \wedge (\texttt{Inj}(f) \vee\ \texttt{Surj}(f))] \rightarrow \texttt{Auto}(f)~~.$$

---

$\texttt{Endo}(f)$ ... $f$ is an endomorphism

$\texttt{Auto}(f)$ ... $f$ is an automorphism

$\texttt{Inj}(f)$ ... $f$ is injective

$\texttt{Surj}(f)$ ... $f$ is surjective

---

Edit: 
As has been pointed out in the comments (and an answer), the statement is only true if $a$ (and therefore $b$) is finite (hence edit). 
As has also been stated in the comments, "There are ways of defining finite that do not involve "cardinality", and the result can be proved accordingly.". Such a proof would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Linear endomorphisms on infinite dimensional vector spaces can be injective and not onto. Consider one that just shifts the elements of a basis:  $x_i\mapsto x_{i+1}$. $x_0$ is not in the image.

Comment: On the other hand, differentiation of functions in surjective but not injective.

Comment: That is true. However, what if one considers just finite sets?

Comment: Endomorphisms, automorphisms in what category?

Comment: Well, then – don’t you need a concept of cardinality to restrict the mere *statement* you want to prove to endomorphisms on *finite* sets?

Comment: @k.stm You are right. That's what thought too while writing the comment.

Comment: @tomasz category of sets

Comment: The question is quite vague. What do you mean "without a concept of cardinality", exactly? I'm pretty sure that if you drop choice, you can have sets which are not finite and satisfy these conditions.

Comment: @tomasz Since I do not have an exact explaination of what I mean, let me put it this way: I would like to have a prove of the statement (which, as Hellen and Francesco Polizzi have pointed out, is not correct in the first place), that does not contain an argument about the number of elements of the domain of $f$. Of course, "the number of elements" is again vague, but its just supposed to be an outline.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Are you asking whether, for a finite set $X$, if a function $f\!:X\to X$ is injective then it is a bijection? How do you define finite? (There are ways of defining finite that do not involve "cardinality", and the result can be proved accordingly.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I wasn't aware of a way to define finite without cardinality. I would appreciate a solution as you have proposed it.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Also, not quite. I am asking if it can be proven without the use of cardinality - not whether it is or not. However, as has already been pointed out, I am not sure anymore this is true for any set, finite or not.

Comment: So... is that the question? "Is there a way to define "finite" that does not explicitly involve cardinalities and that allows us to prove ...?"

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo It was not the original question, but I think it will lead to an answer or another satisfactory result.

Comment: Ok, so: If $X$ is not finite, it is not true that a self-injection is onto, or that a self-surjection is into. If $X$ is finite it is true. The question should be for finite sets then. But "finite" is a notion that involves cardinality. That is the reason why I ask whether the restatement I gave is what you are after. If not, then please be explicit, because the question is completely unclear otherwise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64437/discussion-between-g-chiusole-and-andres-e-caicedo).

Comment: I don't see the point of going elsewhere. All I'm asking is that you clarify your question so someone can help you.

Comment: The question you have reformulated was not my original question. However, as others have pointed out, the question did not make sense. Your reformulation does make sense, but differs from my original question. I think that the answer to your reformulated question will give me a better understanding, which is why I would appreciate hearing the answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, cause it is not true. Say the function f(n)=n+1 on natural numbers.
It is true only in the finite case, and it is the Pigeonhole principle.